# Call Bundler from Ruby specifying the path

Tags: ruby, bundler

I can call bundler using this code:

```
require 'bundler/cli'

begin
  Bundler::CLI.start
rescue Bundler::GemfileNotFound
  puts 'CIRUNNER could not find the Gemfile'
rescue Exception => e
  puts 'CIRUNNER detected and error:'
  puts e
end
```

But Bundler use the current directory as default. My code needs to run bundle install in more than one directory (multiple) projects.

Is there an official way to do that?

Probably the best way is to shell out since I need to run bundle install in its own RVM gemset

Comment: i think that you will need to shell out as RVM manages it's path with the CD command.

Comment: Seems like that here is desc:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226617/bundle-install-via-cli-ruby-system-call
as i get the issue as well